# Possible to make PHP (with pthreads ) to use more than one core?

Tags: php, linux, server

I am using php 5.6 with pthreads installed.

When I run process sometimes I get  1500% of processor use in php ( with top command linux ) using 16 cores intel xeon processor, 64 GB DDR4  on SSD.

Let's consider we open test.php which open 100 threads...is it possible for php to split the process over more than 1 core?

Comment: Yes, its possible.